# I need some help to solve this error: invalid flag: .\App.class

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, java-15

//I man new to java and using VS code for it. I keep on facing this problem and i don't know how to fix it. It keeps showing me error: invalid flag: .\App.class
The code was working fine yesterday, now suddenly it is showing this error. I tried clean the Java language server workspace but it didn't solve the problem.
I need some help.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}

interface Camera {
    void takeSnap();

    void recordVideo();

    default void arka() {
        System.out.println("Default method can be deffined in interface ");
    }
}

interface WiFi {
    String[] getNetwork();

    void connectToNetwork();
}

class MySellphone {
    // public int a = 10;

    void callNo(int no) {
        System.out.println("Calling " + no);
    }

    void pickCall(int no) {
        System.out.println("Connecting " + no);
    }
}

class SmartPhone extends MySellphone implements Camera, WiFi {
    // MySellphone obj = new MySellphone();
    // obj.a=8;

    @Override
    public void takeSnap() {
        System.out.println("Taking snap ");
    }

    @Override
    public void recordVideo() {
        System.out.println("Recording");
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getNetwork() {
        String[] something = { "aa", "ss", "dd" };
        return (something);
    }

    @Override
    public void connectToNetwork() {
        System.out.println("Connected");
    }

}
```

Comment: You have not provided enough information about how you are trying to run the code.  My guess is that you have made some change to the code that means that the app launcher config is broken.  By the way, an `main` method that has no code in the body is never going to work.

Comment: Ignore the main(). How can I fix the app launcher config?

Comment: Then how you run the code? manually execute the command `javac filename.java` in Terminal or click the triangle button on top right corner? Can you describe the progress clearly for me to reproduce your question?